# JavaFX TreeView java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: javafx, treeview

I get the following exception when running a simple program demonstrating the use of the TreeView control:

*java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while creating node:class javafx.scene.layout.StackPane id:null*

The error occurs when expanding or closing TreeItems with children.

Here is the SSCCE:

```
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class TreeViewTest extends Application {
    Tab treeTab;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TabPane pane = new TabPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane,800,600);
        treeTab = new Tab("Tree");
        pane.getTabs().addAll(treeTab);
        primaryStage.setTitle("F(X)yz - Collision Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        makeTree();
    }
    private void makeTree(){
        TreeItem<String> treeItemRoot = new TreeItem<> ("Root");         
        TreeItem<String> nodeItemA = new TreeItem<>("Item A");
        TreeItem<String> nodeItemB = new TreeItem<>("Item B");
        TreeItem<String> nodeItemC = new TreeItem<>("Item C");
        treeItemRoot.getChildren().addAll(nodeItemA, nodeItemB, nodeItemC);        
        TreeItem<String> nodeItemCA = new TreeItem<>("Item CA");
        TreeItem<String> nodeItemCB = new TreeItem<>("Item CB");
        nodeItemC.getChildren().addAll(nodeItemCA, nodeItemCB);         
        TreeItem<String> nodeItemA1 = new TreeItem<>("Item A1");
        TreeItem<String> nodeItemA2 = new TreeItem<>("Item A2");
        TreeItem<String> nodeItemA3 = new TreeItem<>("Item A3");
        nodeItemA.getChildren().addAll(nodeItemA1, nodeItemA2, nodeItemA3);         
        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(treeItemRoot);
        treeTab.setContent(treeView);        
    }        
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is running on jdk1.8.0_162 in Netbeans 8.2 on WIndows 7.

Please can anyone suggest an improvement to get rid of the error.
Thanks.

PS StackTrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while creating node:class javafx.scene.layout.StackPane id:null
NODE INFORMATION
Node:StackPane@5bb0a705[styleClass=tree-disclosure-node] Class:class javafx.scene.layout.StackPane Id:null
Children:[StackPane@401249ef[styleClass=arrow]]
PARENT INFORMATION
Node:TreeViewSkin$1@72fac9c9[styleClass=cell indexed-cell tree-cell]'Root' Class:class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TreeViewSkin$1 Id:null
Children:[Text[text="Root", x=0.0, y=0.0, alignment=LEFT, origin=BASELINE, boundsType=LOGICAL_VERTICAL_CENTER, font=Font[name=System Regular, family=System, style=Regular, size=15.0], fontSmoothingType=LCD, fill=0x333333ff]]

    at org.fxconnector.node.SVNodeFactory.createNode(SVNodeFactory.java:56)
    at org.fxconnector.StageControllerImpl.createNode(StageControllerImpl.java:775)
    at org.fxconnector.StageControllerImpl.lambda$new$10(StageControllerImpl.java:231)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.FXCollections$UnmodifiableObservableListImpl.lambda$new$62(FXCollections.java:929)
    at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:164)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.lambda$new$31(VetoableListDecorator.java:76)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.remove(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:183)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.remove(VetoableListDecorator.java:332)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.remove(VetoableListDecorator.java:221)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_toBack(Parent.java:644)
    at javafx.scene.Node.toBack(Node.java:1756)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TreeCellSkin.updateDisclosureNode(TreeCellSkin.java:186)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TreeCellSkin.layoutChildren(TreeCellSkin.java:211)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.layoutChildren(Control.java:578)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$29(Toolkit.java:398)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:424)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:518)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:491)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$403(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while creating node:class javafx.scene.layout.StackPane id:null
NODE INFORMATION
Node:StackPane@3fb4f2e2[styleClass=tree-disclosure-node] Class:class javafx.scene.layout.StackPane Id:null
Children:[StackPane@b52262b[styleClass=arrow]]
PARENT INFORMATION
Node:TreeViewSkin$1@330b4596[styleClass=cell indexed-cell tree-cell]'Item A' Class:class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TreeViewSkin$1 Id:null
Children:[Text[text="", x=0.0, y=0.0, alignment=LEFT, origin=BASELINE, boundsType=LOGICAL_VERTICAL_CENTER, font=Font[name=System Regular, family=System, style=Regular, size=15.0], fontSmoothingType=LCD, fill=0x333333ff]]

    at org.fxconnector.node.SVNodeFactory.createNode(SVNodeFactory.java:56)
    at org.fxconnector.StageControllerImpl.createNode(StageControllerImpl.java:775)
    at org.fxconnector.StageControllerImpl.lambda$new$10(StageControllerImpl.java:231)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.FXCollections$UnmodifiableObservableListImpl.lambda$new$62(FXCollections.java:929)
    at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:164)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.lambda$new$31(VetoableListDecorator.java:76)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.remove(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:183)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.remove(VetoableListDecorator.java:332)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.remove(VetoableListDecorator.java:221)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_toBack(Parent.java:644)
    at javafx.scene.Node.toBack(Node.java:1756)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TreeCellSkin.updateDisclosureNode(TreeCellSkin.java:186)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TreeCellSkin.layoutChildren(TreeCellSkin.java:211)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.layoutChildren(Control.java:578)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$29(Toolkit.java:398)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:424)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:518)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:491)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$403(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while creating node:class javafx.scene.layout.StackPane id:null
NODE INFORMATION
Node:StackPane@4a2a9995[styleClass=tree-disclosure-node] Class:class javafx.scene.layout.StackPane Id:null
Children:[StackPane@5483de69[styleClass=arrow]]
PARENT INFORMATION
Node:TreeViewSkin$1@269becf3[styleClass=cell indexed-cell tree-cell]'Item C' Class:class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TreeViewSkin$1 Id:null
Children:[Text[text="", x=0.0, y=0.0, alignment=LEFT, origin=BASELINE, boundsType=LOGICAL_VERTICAL_CENTER, font=Font[name=System Regular, family=System, style=Regular, size=15.0], fontSmoothingType=LCD, fill=0x333333ff]]

    at org.fxconnector.node.SVNodeFactory.createNode(SVNodeFactory.java:56)
    at org.fxconnector.StageControllerImpl.createNode(StageControllerImpl.java:775)
    at org.fxconnector.StageControllerImpl.lambda$new$10(StageControllerImpl.java:231)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.FXCollections$UnmodifiableObservableListImpl.lambda$new$62(FXCollections.java:929)
    at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:164)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.lambda$new$31(VetoableListDecorator.java:76)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.remove(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:183)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.remove(VetoableListDecorator.java:332)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.remove(VetoableListDecorator.java:221)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_toBack(Parent.java:644)
    at javafx.scene.Node.toBack(Node.java:1756)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TreeCellSkin.updateDisclosureNode(TreeCellSkin.java:186)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TreeCellSkin.layoutChildren(TreeCellSkin.java:211)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.layoutChildren(Control.java:578)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$29(Toolkit.java:398)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:424)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:518)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:491)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$403(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: hmm ... worksform in 8_151 and 9_01 - would not expect an "intermediate" misbehaviour in 8_161. On the other hand: faintly remember having seen a weird bug around treeView recently, but can't find it ... could you please add the stacktrace?

Comment: hmm ... org.fxconnector is not a core fx package, or is it? Where does it come from?

Comment: That got me worried so I copied the file to a 'clean project - I still get the error when I run it. However, googling org.fxconnector.node.SVNodeFactory has led me to the ScenicView source code. I then remembered I had ScenicView running!!!

Comment: After the closing ScenicView the test program now works as expected. Thanks for your comment. I still think it is probably a bug as I don't think that ScenicView should cause a RuntimeException.

Comment: glad you found the reason :) Most probably a bug, I would suspect ScenicView to be the culprit ...

Comment: Just to confirm, had the exact same problem here. Running Javafx 11.0.2 under linux and also saw the stacktraces. I also had ScenicView running in the background. Closed it and the stacktrace is gone! :) thanks @jimbo8 for leading me to it :)

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this as well so I'll put the @jimbo8's comment as the answer:

This is caused by [ScenicView](https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view).

Close ScenicView and you won't get this error anymore.